# Effective Theory for Matter Fields Coupled to a Chern-Simons Field

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, effective-field-theory, quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory

Assuming that matter fields coupled with the background Chern-Simons field (or Maxwell-Chern-Simons field), I want to obtain the effective theory in terms of matter fields only, by integrating out a Chern-Simons gauge field. The resulting effective theory should be a nonlinear sigma model with a Wess-Zumino term, which is physically related to the description of the low-energy physics of the quantum Hall effect. Can anyone suggest relevant literature or reference on this topic?

Comment: Hi @Merlin Zhang. Which kind of effective action? Wilsonian? 1PI?

Comment: More similar to Wilsonian effective action.